# Self referencing canonical tag in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/pub/pdf-docs/.*$ [NC]
```

I need all the pdf files in the assets/pub/pdf-docs folder to have a self referencing canonical https header tag.
How can I do this with one(ish) line(s) of code in the htaccess file?

I cannot apply it to just pdf files because the pdfs in assets/pvt/pdf-docs are excluded from indexing.

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "excluded from indexing", and what does that have to do with the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: assets/pvt has no index tag set.

<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/assets/pvt/#">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, noarchive, nosnippet"
</If>

Issue is that google is chosing old pdfs that are 404 to be canonical and ignoring correct PDFs.
Correct PDFs are in sitemap.

Comment: _"assets/pvt has no index tag set."_ - relevance? And what does that have to do with the `/assets/pub/pdf-docs/` path? _"Issue is that google is chosing old pdfs that are 404 to be canonical"_ - what does that even mean, "choosing to be canonical"?

Comment: relevance is that I cannot use a general rule for pdf files, it needs to be targeting a specific folder. 404 means not found. These pdfs do not exist anymore yet google is still showing them as indexed in GSC and canonical despite the replacement pdfs having a 200 code. Issue persists after a month.

Comment: So why not say that you need this for PDFs inside/below a specific folder then, instead of talking about other folders being "indexed" or not. And what is the actual _problem_ now? If you were able to add headers specifically for the content of the folder `assets/pvt` using `<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/assets/pvt/#">`, then where is the problem with using a similar restriction for what you need to apply to PDFs in the other folder only?

Comment: The problem is exactly as stated in the question. I am looking for a rule that will apply a self referencing canonical http tag to each PDF file in the given folder. The reason for mentioning other folders is to exclude the option of a rule that just targets .pdf extensions.

Comment: You can not set headers with a RewriteRule, you need to do it the same way you did with the X-Robots-Tag for the other folder ... Write an If condition for PDF files contained in your target folder, and for those, set the header.

Comment: yes but how can I write the if condition to get the path, filename and extension of each pdf and put it together as an x-robots canonical tag. I cannot find anything on google about how to do that.

Comment: The if condition doesn't need to be for _each_ PDF, it should use wildcards. And the full requested path you got already, that's `%{REQUEST_URI}` - so combine that with protocol and server name, to create an absolute URL.

Comment: Adding a self-referencing-canonical tag to the "new" PDFs is not going to help you (if that is what you are intending). You need to 301 redirect from the "old" to the corresponding "new" PDF (if indeed the "new" PDF is a replacement for the "old"). (Adding a self-referencing-canonical is only going to help if the same PDF is accessible from different URLs - but this doesn't seem to have anything to do with your current issue. And that isn't something you could do in `.htaccess`, unless you do it one-by-one for each PDF.)

Comment: Is this the correct code for the canonical? <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/assets/pub/pdf-docs/#">
Header add Link "< https://www.example.com/assets/pub/pdf-docs/%{FILENAME}.pdf >; rel=\"canonical\""
</If>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Set env var CANONICAL_URL 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^assets/pub/pdf-docs/.+\.pdf$ - [E=CANONICAL_URL:https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}]

Header add Link '<%{CANONICAL_URL}e>; rel="canonical"' env=CANONICAL_URL
```

The mod_rewrite directives set an environment variable `CANONICAL_URL` if an existing `.pdf` file in the stated URL-path is requested. The `Header` directive then sets a `rel="canonical"` `Link` header, using this env var (ie. `%{CANONICAL_URL}e`), but only if this env var is set.

In order to retrieve the canonical hostname, this is dependent on either the hostname already being canonicalised (ie. www vs non-www etc.) prior to these directives OR `UseCanonicalName On` and `ServerName` is set appropriately in the server config (otherwise `SERVER_NAME` is simply the same as `HTTP_HOST` - the value of the HTTP `Host` header). If this is not the case then hardcode the canonical hostname in place of `%{SERVER_NAME}`.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

---

> Issue is that google is chosing old pdfs that are 404 to be canonical and ignoring correct PDFs. Correct PDFs are in sitemap.

**HOWEVER**, as I stated in comments, setting this self-referential canonical tag on the new PDF is not going to help you - it's not going to prevent the old PDFs (that return a 404) from appearing in the search results.

For that, you need to 301 (permanent) redirect the old PDFs to the new to inform search engines that the old PDFs have moved to a new URL (and to redirect users from the search engine's search results)<sup>***1**</sup>. A separate sitemap containing only the "old" PDFs (that now redirect) can also help search engines with crawling the old URLs and discovering the redirect. Adding this sitemap to GSC will give you an idea of the index status of these old (and out of date) URLs.

<sup>***1** This is assuming that the PDFs have simply changed URL and not entirely new and unrelated. In this case a redirect would not be appropriate and you should serve a "410 Gone" and request these old URLs be removed from the SERPs using Google's URL removal tool to expedite the removal process.</sup>

(Adding a self-referential-canonical tag is only going to help if the same PDF is accessible from different URLs - but this is irrelevant to your current issue. And that isn't something you could necessarily do in `.htaccess`, unless you do it one-by-one for each PDF, or there is a discernible pattern that allows you to generate the canonical URL regardless of the request.)